# Webscrape w/o beautiful soup

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, function, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping and python in general, but I was a tad bit stuck on how to correct my function. My task is to scrape the site of words starting with a specific letter and return a list of the ones that match, preferably using regex. Thank you for your time, here is my code so far below.

```
import urllib
import re

def webscraping(website):
    fhand = urllib.urlopen(website).read()
    for line in fhand:
        line = fhand.strip()
        if line.startswith('h'):
            print line
webscraping("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping")
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use beautiful soup?

Comment: we have not learned how to use beautiful soup in my programming class and all the resources I tried were using it

Comment: Don't try it and re-invent the wheel. Web scrapers will make your life much easier than trying to use regex for scraping. If the page changes then all your regex will no longer pull the data you need, depending on how the page has been modified and if your regex no longer picks up the values you need/want.

Answer (score 1):

Going to go ahead and say this:

```
and return a list of the ones that match, preferably using regex.
```

No. You <strike>don't</strike> absolutely shouldn't use regex to parse HTML. That's why we have HTML parsers exactly for that job.

Use `BeautifulSoup`, it has everything built-in and it's relatively easy to do something like this: (Not tested)

```
def webscraping(website):

   fhand = urllib.urlopen(website).read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(fhand, "html.parser")
   soup.find_all(text=lambda x: x.startswith('h'))
```

Answer (score 0):

never use regex to parse HTML, you can use Beautiful Soup
here is an example

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

todo = list()
visited = list()
url = raw_input('Enter - ')
todo.append(url)

while len(todo) > 0 :
   print "====== Todo list count is ",len(todo)
   url = todo.pop()

   if ( not url.startswith('http') ) : 
       print "Skipping", url
       continue

   if ( url.find('facebook') > 0 ) :
       continue

   if ( url in visited ) :
       print "Visited", url
       continue

   print "===== Retrieving ", url

   html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
   visited.append(url)

   # Retrieve all of the anchor tags
   tags = soup('a')
   for tag in tags:
       newurl = tag.get('href', None)
       if ( newurl != None ) : 
           todo.append(newurl)
```